# Wordpress backend buttons all redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

Very peculiar problem:

All buttons on the Wordpress backend that change some state (Update, Preview Changes, Save Changes on Permalinks, etc.) are all redirecting to the homepage without saving.

While troubleshooting, I was able to change the permalink to default and that worked fine, though it didn't fix the redirecting problem, but changing it to anything else does the redirect. So now I need to fix the redirect issue and get permalink back to what they were (/post-name)

Already disabled all plugins and went to default theme and the problem still existed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new at this, so take this with a grain of salt, but I am always surprised at what old cookies etc. do to stuff like that.   Have you tried deleting cookies in internet options?   Just a thought.   I'll be watching to see if that works, or if something else does.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I've tried in multiple browsers and cleared server-side and client-side caches.